# Door closing transition in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, transition

I'm trying to make the door closing transition like what we can see in Kingdom Rush. (Two doors coming from the left and the right)

What I'm thinking is two approaches:

- The first one could be a custom transition getting input as a door image

  For this approach, I could not find a way to do it although it is my preferable way
- Second approach could be creating the door closing animation on the first scene and push the second scene with the same door closed on the second scene. After that do the door opening animation.

  This approach is possible but I wonder if there will be a blink in the scene transition

Has anyone come across this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd suggest the 2nd one.
it's rather easy to that...something like this:

make an animation in a separate class and in your scene just call the animation to close at the end of the scene and replace the next scene with :`[[CCDirector sharedDirector]replaceScene:[NextScene scene]];`

If your scene loads relatively fast..it won't blink at all..but if it does (for some reason) make another thread and add "big things" to the next scene in a background thread so that the scene loads instantly, and in the time you animate the doors load the rest .

To detect if the doors are closed...just set a `NSUserDefaults` BOOL to YES in 1st scene and in the 2nd check if the door is closed.

As for the animation itself just make 2 ccsprites outside the screen and then animate them on the screen.Also..because the sprites are already in memory when you leave the scene, you won't need to load anything in the next scene..so it's instant.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it worked really well. Still I'm so tempted to try the first approach. But for now, it's good enough

Comment: well because it's a...weird transition..you'd have to pass the sprites into the transition or subclass CCTransition and make your own (tho i still don't know how to make a custom transition). So if you succeed i'd love too see how you did it. And fyi ..i'm trying to start a cocos2d chat room...join:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the CCTransition.m file in cocos2d sources. There in flip transition classes you can find examples of CCOrbitCamera action usage. In case of scenes it flips them relatieve to their center. But all transitions are made relatieve to node's anchor point. So you can try out different variants.